# How to avoid logout after a refresh on an Angular project?

Tags: angular

I am in a project in Angular 4 in which, after login, I need to avoid that when the user refreshes the page (F5), log out of the system. Is there any parameter I can change to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Well you should read the answer from @Jolleyboy, but as a side note, lets put you in that situation, let's say that you enter to a web page that don't let you go because you have logged in, I cannot imagine a case when you go out of that page with a good experience.

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is called session management.  A simplistic approach would be writing an object to localstorage, sessionstorage, or a cookie that you can check to see if a client is logged in, preferably with a timestamp that you can check to force them to re-login if they haven't logged in over a specific interval.  Note that this *not* a secure approach.

A more in depth approach would be using something like [JWT](https://jwt.io/%20%22JWT) though [this isn't always suggested.](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/why-jwts-suck-as-session-tokens)

Either way, with Angular 4, you'll validate that a user is logged in (typically with a [route guard](https://angular.io/guide/router#guards)), and if they are, the user will no longer be logged out after refreshing the page.  If not, the route guard will redirect the user to the login page/component

See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cPNTKy1Lq9s) or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgqO-3FAvds) for a video guide of how to approach session management with Angular.